# Speeding up integration methods MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am using MATLAB to execute a triple integral using integral3 and it is running very slow. I was wondering if there ways to speed it. I am guessing its due to the fact that I set the abstol wrong. Not sure how to handle it. PS the code below works with no syntax error. There are a couple of things I dont know how to pick, abstol, method etc..

```
clear all
syms gamma1
syms gamma2
syms z
syms v 

Nt=16; sigmanoise=10^(-7.9); c3=0.129; c1=(1-c3)/2;a2=0;b2=0; 
a1=0.0030; b1= 0.0030; A1=  1.5625e-04,A2=0;  B1= 7.8125e-05;B2=0;
theta= 3.1623;lambda1=  4.9736e-05;lambda2=0;p1=1;p2=0; alpha1=2; alpha2=4;delta1=2/alpha1; delta2=2/alpha2;beta1=0.025; beta2=0.025;


a= gamma1^-1+gamma2^-1+2*gamma1^(-0.5)*gamma2^(-0.5);
laplacesgi=(exp(+2*pi*j.*z*a)-1)./(2*pi*j*z);
laplacesgi=matlabFunction(laplacesgi);


laplacenoi=exp(-2*pi*j.*z*theta*sigmanoise/Nt);
laplacenoi=matlabFunction(laplacenoi);


interfere= @(gamma1,gamma2,v,z)( (1 -2*c1-c3./(1+2*pi*j*z*theta*v.^(-1))).*(A1.*(v).^(delta1-1).*exp(-a1.*(v).^ (delta1./2))+B1.*(v).^(delta2-1) .*(1-exp(-b1.*(v).^ (delta2./2))))); 
gscalar =@(gamma1,gamma2,z)integral(@(v)(interfere(gamma1,gamma2,v,z)),gamma2,inf);
g = @(gamma1,gamma2,z)arrayfun(gscalar,gamma1,gamma2,z);

lp= A1*(gamma1)^(delta1-1)*exp(-a1*(gamma1)^ (delta1/2))+B1*(gamma1)^(delta2-1)*(1-exp(-b1*(gamma1)^ (delta2/2)))+A2*gamma1^(delta1-1)*exp(-a2*gamma1^(delta1/2))+ B2*gamma1^(delta2-1)*(1-exp(-b2*gamma1^ (delta2/2)));%;
dk1=((2*pi*lambda1))/(beta1^2)*(1-exp(-a1*(gamma2)^(delta1/2))*(1+(gamma2)^(delta1/2)*a1))+ pi*lambda1*gamma2^(delta2)*p1^delta2-((2*pi*lambda1)/(beta1^2))*(1-exp(-b1*(gamma2)^(delta2/2))*(1+(gamma2)^(delta2/2)*b1));
dk2=((2*pi*lambda2))/(beta2^2)*(1-exp(-a2*(gamma2)^(delta1/2))*(1+(gamma2)^(delta1/2)*a2))+ pi*lambda2*gamma2^(delta2)*p2^delta2-((2*pi*lambda2)/(beta2^2))*(1-exp(-b2*(gamma2)^(delta2/2))*(1+(gamma2)^(delta2/2)*b2));
dk=dk1+dk2;
lcp= A1*(gamma2)^(delta1-1)*exp(-a1*(gamma2)^ (delta1/2))+B1*(gamma2)^(delta2-1)*(1-exp(-b1*(gamma2)^ (delta2/2)))+A2*gamma2^(delta1-1)*exp(-a2*gamma2^ (delta1/2))+ B2*gamma2^(delta2-1)*(1-exp(-b2*gamma2^(delta2/2)));%;

pdflast=lp*lcp*exp(-dk);
pdflast=matlabFunction(pdflast);
pdflast= @(gamma1,gamma2)arrayfun(pdflast,gamma1,gamma2);
gamma2min=@(gamma1)gamma1;
warning('off','MATLAB:integral:MinStepSize');
T = integral3(@(gamma1,gamma2,z)(laplacenoi(z).*laplacesgi(gamma1,gamma2,z).*pdflast(gamma1,gamma2).*exp(-g(gamma1,gamma2,z))),0,inf,@(gamma2)gamma2,inf,0.05,1000,'abstol',1e-3)
```

I appreciate any ideas or suggestions.

Comment: Posting the input data would help...

Comment: We don't know if for example `laplacenoi` is a function or vector. Whatever it is, please provide complete input. You could also try using `profile` to identify slow lines.

Comment: @Daniel please check my edit, you can see that I divided it into 5 parts, the integrand of integral3 has 4 embedded functions, that are in turn in function of z gamma1 gamma2. Please let me know if I can make it more clear

Comment: These lines kill your performance `laplacenoi = @(z)arrayfun(laplacenoi,z);` rewrite your functions to accept vectorized inputs directly, using element wise operations `.*` where needed. Then you don't need arrayfun

Comment: Thanks, this can be done for both laplacenoi and laplacesgi right? but not for interfere..@Daniel

Comment: `matlabFunction` should return vectorized functions, I don't really see why you have the `arrayfun` for `laplacenoi` in the first place.

Comment: yup i changed that. Do you have any more suggestions, for example, the tolerance error that I chose does it make sense? @ChristopherCreutzig

Comment: For a start, copy and paste the code in your question back into your Matlab Editor and fix all of the syntax errors and line wrap issues that it's warning you about. When the code runs, edit this question and paste the fixed version back in. Also, your question specifically about the last line with `integral3` being slow, right?

Comment: What @horchler said. There's any number of syntax errors in your code, plus code bits and pieces that should not be there. And an 'abstol' of 1e-30 when computing in double only makes sense if all your intermediate values as well as the end result are very small.

Comment: @horchler thanks but I don't understand what do you mean by syntax error and line wrap issues? The code does run with no errors it just take alot of time to execute. And yes I am talking at integral3.

Comment: some of the constants I didn't add to the code, here such as c1, a1,a2, b1,b2, A1, theta... these are all non negative constants and wont add much value to the code here.

Comment: Did you try exactly what I suggested: copy/paste the code in the gray box above directly into your Editor? What `version` of Matlab are you using? Commas in the `syms` line at the top stop `gamma2` and `z` from even being defined. You have carriage returns on multiple lines instead of using `...` to continue the line until the terminating semicolon. Lastly, there are two apparent syntax issues related to parentheses – one related to the `gscalar = ...` line and the other the `integral3` line.

Comment: @ChristopherCreutzig thanks but what do you mean by intermediate values?

Comment: Better, but it still doesn't run. `theta` isn't defined (and  other things after that too). `clear all` or put this in a function (with no input arguments) to limit the scope of your variables and make sure it's still runnable and everything in the code is defined.

Comment: @horchler please check my new edited code, if you copy past it it works perfectly fine.

Comment: can you please let me know if it works now @horchler

Comment: Finally runs. I ran it for an hour with the profiler and it didn't finish. Your integration of the `interfere` function appears to be the most expensive part so you might focus on optimizing that. Also check that you don't have a bug in your equations. Your use of symbolic math seems completely superfluous. In many cases you've created anonymous functions with unused arguments. And, as @Daniel says, you should also consider replacing instances of `arrayfun` with regular function that accomplish what is needed efficiently.

Comment: I thnk I can get rid of arrayfun from the pdflast, but from interfere I think I can't, arrayfun is the only way to vectorize it. Do you agree?

Comment: Also the problem is that interfere includes an integration over v, and should  end up with variables gamma1, gamma2, z... It is such a complicated problem as you see.

Comment: Since I can't even get this to finish calculating (how long does it take?) I'll just make more suggestions. Writing everything as a bunch of anonymous functions will also result in slower code with greater function call overhead. Much better to write larger regular sub-functions. Then you can easily calculate values that are reused. Debugging may be more straightforward too. Use anonymous functions only at the end to create closures to [pass your parameters](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/parameterizing-functions.html) (don't use `global` variables).

Comment: `arrayfun` is nothing more than a `for` loop in disguise. You can *always* replace it with a loop (you just need to determine the `numel` of the array arguments). In this case I don't think that you can replace the `arrayfun` with simple vectorized code as with the `pdflast` case because `integral` doesn't accept vectors integration bounds (I run into that issue myself all of the time).

Comment: that is the whole problem, i hate that integral doesnt accept vector integration bound, i think that is the main problem in my case.

Comment: If you have trouble I think it might be good for you to look at your problem mathematically to see how it might be restructured for numerical calculation. Can elements be moved out of the integral? Are there singularities in the domain that cause issues? Are terms/equations constant or linear or purely real-valued in certain cases? Can anything be simplified, cancelled or re-expressed? If you're going to use symbolic math, those are the sorts of things I'd use it for.

Comment: i see your point. I will try that. thanks for your help, I appreciate it.

Comment: I have one more question, when I perform the integral for interfere, if I replace the command by this   {gscalar =@(gamma1,gamma2,z)integral(@(v)(interfere(gamma1,gamma2,v,z)),gamma2,inf, 'asbtol',1e-3);} do you think it wil make it run faster. @horchler notice I added an abstol of 1e-3.

Comment: It might a bit. You should also re-do your function handles. `interfere` is not a function of `gamma1` and `gamma2` and `gscalar` itself is not s function of `gamma1`. No idea if such things improve performance much, but it makes for better, easier to understand code.

Comment: gscalar is a function of gamma1, note that the lower limit of integral is gamma2.

Comment: @George: `integral(@foo,a,b,'abstol',1e-30)` can possibly work only if: (a) The end result is somewhere between `-1e-15` and `1e-15` and (b) all values `foo(x)` and all the intermediate sums are in that range, too. And that is really a theoretical maximum limit. The `1e-3` you now have makes much more sense, and if your end result is not likely to be really close to zero, looking at `reltol` would be even better. Values very close to 0 are the only ones where you have to use absolute tolerance, and if you don't have to, you want relative tolerance in probably 99% of all cases.

Comment: I seriously doubt your code does what you mean. Your definition of `interfere` does not use its inputs `gamma1` and `gamma2` anywhere. Meaning that `gscalar` cannot have a finite value unless you happen to sit right on a zero of the `interfere` function. Check: `interfere(1,1,1,1)` and `interfere(1,100,1,1)` are probably meant to have different values. (One general comment: Try and make your code more easily readable. Even if it is “only” yourself, the primary goal of code is communicating *with a human.*

Comment: Christoper, thanks actually the numbers are very close to zero the integral should generate a number between 0 and 1.  ...@ChristopherCreutzig

Comment: Also note that gscalar, is the integral of interfere, from a lower limit gama2 to +inf and since integral doesnt accept a limit as variable I had to do it this way. do you understand what I mean, integral requires the limit to be a scalar@ChristopherCreutzig

Comment: What am I trying to say is that in order for me to perform the numerical integration of intefere from gamma2 to +inf , I have to take numerical values of gamma2 and z because of the way integral accepts only numerical values. But note that in the end I have to integrate over gamma2 and z;  therefore, I have to write it in this way until integral3 command is executed and assigns numerical values of z and gamma2 then integral iin turn can be executed. Does this make sense? @ChristopherCreutzig

Answer (score 0):

This is getting way too long for a comment, and while it doesn't really give an answer either, I think it may be helpful anyway, so I will slightly abuse the answer form for it.

## Code Readability

I don't think your code as it stands fulfills the basic fundamental purpose of code: Communicating with a human being, probably yourself down the road.

I don't know if the variable names are unambiguous enough that in six months, they will still tell you exactly what is what. If they are, great. If not, you may want to improve upon them. (And yes, naming stuff is one of the hardest parts of programming, but that doesn't make it less important.)

The same holds true for comments: If you don't need comments on your formulas, more power to you. I have no idea what you are computing, so the fact that I don't understand your formulas doesn't mean much. But again, think of yourself in a few months, looking for a problem: Would you have wished for a comment such that you know if that factor is really correct or off by one?

Here's something I do know: Your formulas are simply too wide to be comprehended at once. Simple reformatting helps to see the structure better. Here's how I reformatted your code to start making heads or tails from it:

```
clear all
syms gamma1
syms gamma2
syms z
syms v 

Nt=16;
sigmanoise=10^(-7.9);
c3=0.129;
c1=(1-c3)/2;
a2=0;
b2=0; 
a1=0.0030;
b1=0.0030;
A1=1.5625e-04;
A2=0;
B1=7.8125e-05;
B2=0;
theta=3.1623;
lambda1=4.9736e-05;
lambda2=0;
p1=1;
p2=0;
alpha1=2;
alpha2=4;
delta1=2/alpha1;
delta2=2/alpha2;
beta1=0.025;
beta2=0.025;


a=gamma1^(-1)+gamma2^(-1)+2*gamma1^(-0.5)*gamma2^(-0.5);
laplacesgi=matlabFunction((exp(2*pi*1j*z*a)-1)./(2*pi*1j*z));
laplacenoi=matlabFunction(exp(-2*pi*1j*z*theta*sigmanoise/Nt));


interfere= @(gamma1,gamma2,v,z)( ...
  (1 -2*c1-c3./(1+2*pi*j*z*theta*v.^(-1))).*(A1.*v.^(delta1-1).* ...
    exp(-a1.*v.^(delta1./2))+B1.*v.^(delta2-1).*(1-exp(-b1.*v.^(delta2./2))))); 
gscalar=@(gamma1,gamma2,z)integral(@(v)(interfere(gamma1,gamma2,v,z)),gamma2,inf);
g=@(gamma1,gamma2,z)arrayfun(gscalar,gamma1,gamma2,z);

lp=A1*gamma1^(delta1-1)*exp(-a1*gamma1^(delta1/2))+ ...
    B1*gamma1^(delta2-1)*(1-exp(-b1*gamma1^(delta2/2)))+ ...
   A2*gamma1^(delta1-1)*exp(-a2*gamma1^(delta1/2))+ ...
    B2*gamma1^(delta2-1)*(1-exp(-b2*gamma1^(delta2/2)));
dk1=((2*pi*lambda1))/(beta1^2)*(1-exp(-a1*gamma2^(delta1/2))*(1+gamma2^(delta1/2)*a1))+ ...
  pi*lambda1*gamma2^(delta2)*p1^delta2- ...
  ((2*pi*lambda1)/(beta1^2))*(1-exp(-b1*gamma2^(delta2/2))*(1+gamma2^(delta2/2)*b1));
dk2=((2*pi*lambda2))/(beta2^2)*(1-exp(-a2*gamma2^(delta1/2))*(1+gamma2^(delta1/2)*a2))+ ...
  pi*lambda2*gamma2^(delta2)*p2^delta2- ...
  ((2*pi*lambda2)/(beta2^2))*(1-exp(-b2*gamma2^(delta2/2))*(1+gamma2^(delta2/2)*b2));
dk=dk1+dk2;
lcp=A1*gamma2^(delta1-1)*exp(-a1*gamma2^(delta1/2))+ ...
      B1*gamma2^(delta2-1)*(1-exp(-b1*gamma2^(delta2/2)))+ ...
    A2*gamma2^(delta1-1)*exp(-a2*gamma2^(delta1/2))+ ...
      B2*gamma2^(delta2-1)*(1-exp(-b2*gamma2^(delta2/2)));

pdflast=matlabFunction(lp*lcp*exp(-dk));
pdflast=@(gamma1,gamma2)arrayfun(pdflast,gamma1,gamma2);
gamma2min=@(gamma1)gamma1;
T = integral3(@(gamma1,gamma2,z)( ...
  laplacenoi(z).*laplacesgi(gamma1,gamma2,z).*pdflast(gamma1,gamma2).*exp(-g(gamma1,gamma2,z))), ...
  0,inf,...
  @(gamma2)gamma2,inf,...
  0.05,1000,...
  'abstol',1e-3)
```

A few notes one this:

- MATLAB is one of the languages that require an indication that the logical line should continue after the physical line break. The indication in MATLAB is three dots.
- Get rid of any and all warnings the MATLAB editor shows you. In very rare cases, by disabling the warning for this line; usually, by correcting your code. Some of these warnings may seem over-protective, but coe quickly reaches the point where none of us can have enough of it in our minds to see the more subtle problems, and linting helps avoid a fair number of them, in my experience.
- Consistent spacing helps, in the same way “proper” (i.e., standardized) spelling makes reading English easier: The patterns are just much more obvious.
- Line breaks should in general not be done haphazardly, but emphasizing the structure of commands and formulas. In several of your formulas, I have seen symmetries between input parameters and tried to make them obvious by placing the line breaks accordingly. That helps a lot when looking for typos.
- Your code has lines such as these:

  `pdflast=lp*lcp*exp(-dk);`

  `pdflast=matlabFunction(pdflast);`

  I used to recycle variables like that, too. Over time, I learned the hard way that it helps for debugging and readability not to, especially if your values have different types, as they do here.

There are a few points I would still clean up at this point. For example, `pdflast` works just fine on arrays and the line `pdflast= @(gamma1,gamma2)arrayfun(pdflast,gamma1,gamma2);` should be deleted, and the lower bound for `gamma2` in the `integral3` call is a function of `gamma1` and should be changed to `@(gamma1)gamma1`.

Does the computer/MATLAB care about any of this? Maybe something slipped in where it does, but basically: No. All of these changes are for you, and if you send your code in an SO post, for us, the readers.

## (Likely) Bug: Vectorization

I think your definition of `g` is wrong:

```
g=@(gamma1,gamma2,z)arrayfun(gscalar,gamma1,gamma2,z);
```

The cubature (i.e., `integral3`) will try to call this function with non-scalar values for one or more of the parameters. Most likely, these will not all be of the same size, and even if they were, it would expect to get a 3D result, not a vector. Try calling your `g` that way:

```
>> g(1:2,1,1)
Error using arrayfun
All of the input arguments must be of the same size and shape.
Previous inputs had size 2 in dimension 2. Input #3 has size 1

Error in @(gamma1,gamma2,z)arrayfun(gscalar,gamma1,gamma2,z)
```

It's really a good idea to check intermediate building blocks like that. What your really need to have is an `arrayfun` over `gamma2`, something like this:

```
gscalar=@(gamma1,gamma2,z) ...
    integral(@(v)(interfere(gamma1,gamma2,v,z)),gamma2,inf, ...
      'ArrayValued',true);

g = @(gamma1,gamma2,z)arrayfun(@(gamma2)gscalar(gamma1,gamma2,z),gamma2);
```

## (Possible) Bug: Definition of `interfere`

I don't know if you tried checking `interfere` against any known or suspected values. (Sanity checks for formulas I just typed seem a really good idea to me.) I somehow doubt that the formula is correctly capturing your intent:

```
interfere=@(gamma1,gamma2,v,z)( ...
  (1-2*c1-c3./(1+2*pi*1j*z*theta*v.^(-1))).*(A1.*v.^(delta1-1).* ...
    exp(-a1.*v.^(delta1./2))+B1.*v.^(delta2-1).*(1-exp(-b1.*v.^(delta2./2)))));
```

The potential problem with this formula (apart from a somewhat inconsistent use of `*` vs. `.*` etc.) is that *the values do not depend on `gamma1` and `gamma2` at all.*

Of course, that can happen, but if you actually mean it to be the case, what is the rationale for including `gamma1` in the formula in the first place?

If this is as it should be, you may need to still make the result the proper size: Right now, `interfere` simply ignores its first two inputs, which may trip up the integrator: `interfere(1:3,1,1,1)` should return a 3-element vector.

## Concluding Thoughts

As you may have noticed, your question did not get a satisfying answer yet. Nor do I think in its current form it will. To get volunteers to look at your problem, you need to make it easy to understand what you are doing:

- Start by simplifying your formulas. They may not be of interest to you anymore, but right now, they're just clutter.
- Trim down your parameters. That is somehow part of the above.
- Throw out things that are probably irrelevant. Apart from the point that you don't need (and probably don't want) an additional `arrayfun` around the `matlabFunction` results, symbolic math is likely to be irrelevant to your actua question on `integral3`. If you can ask your question without it, it may attract more attention.
- For anything you cannot trim down, consider explaining what is happening.

Of course, in this process, for each iteration, test your code (after saying `clear all` or in a fresh MATLAB session!) to check if the problem is still there. If it is not, you may have found a hint where your basic problem is hiding.

For a longer discussion on the topic, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18584/how-to-ask-a-smart-question and the guides linked to within that discussion.